# Are there any partial or complete set bonuses in Kingdoms of Amalur?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

In other games where set items exist (I'm specifically thinking of Diablo II) there are partial or complete set bonuses, additional bonuses that are applied for having and wearing the entire set.

Does KoA follow this mechanic and provide an additional bonus for completing a set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It gives set bonuses based on how many pieces you have, and doesn't always require completion to get the best set bonus possible. See my screenshot below, which shows one piece of the "Captain's" set.

[image]

- The area circled in green shows what types of pieces exist in the set (helm, torso, pants, gloves, boots).
- The area circled in orange lists the bonuses you'll get as you add more pieces of the set (so 2 pieces gives you +20% health, 3 pieces adds +20% mana, etc)

There do not appear to be any hidden "complete" set bonuses. So notice that while this set has 5 pieces, the set bonuses only go up to 4 pieces. Adding in a 5th piece has no special effect.

Comment: There is no denying it ... Rogues rule!

Answer (score 2):

An easy example is the [Mass Effect 3 Armor Set](http://www.ign.com/wikis/kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning/Mass_Effect_3_Armor_Set), available from the Special Delivery chest in Gorhart (after you enter in the DLC code that comes with new copies of the game). It has the following set bonuses:

> - (2 pieces) +10 Armor
> - (3 pieces) +0.1 Health Regen per Second
> - (3 pieces) +1 Mana Regen per Second
> - (4 pieces) +10% Elemental Resistance

There does not seem to be any bonus for wearing all 5 pieces of the set.

Answer (score 0):

I have played through the majority of the game.  If you max out blacksmithing and add 8 points to sagecraft you will be able to construct substantially more helpful equipment then you will ever get with any set.

The sets that are available are not useless BUT they aren't as effective as blacksmithing your own throughout the game.  That being said, set items are worth the most when selling and will help a great deal in purchasing repair kits, lockpicks, and potions throughout the game.  Even with out blacksithing, there is not a set equivalent to any level that is substantially better than green, blues, and purps that become available.  It is also very hard to complete the best sets as some are in special chests and others are drop only and very rare.

Edit:

I realize i didn't perfectly answer the question.  Yes, their are partial and completed sets in the game.

Comment: You're not going to wear a whole set very often, but there are a lot of sets where a couple pieces are worth wearing together.